# bootstrap accordion how tell when other div are collapse (grab id of other div) in javascript no jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
    <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
        <h2 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link btn-block text-left" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
            Collapsible Group Item #1
        </button>
        </h2>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
        <div id = "test1 "class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
        <h2 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link btn-block text-left collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
            Collapsible Group Item #2
        </button>
        </h2>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
        <div id = "test2" class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
        <h2 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link btn-block text-left collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
            Collapsible Group Item #3
        </button>
        </h2>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
        <div id = "test3" class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

hi so when I open two of the "n" number of paragraph one of the paragraph closes. I want to grab that paragraph id that automatically closes in javascript (so the div that has id as test1, test2, test3 (the one that automatically closes when you open the second one). I am fairyly new so I have not use jquery yet. I am using the latest bootstrap. Thanks in advance 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/collapse/#events

Comment: thanks. But I meant how do I get the id of the one that is about to hide.I print this.id and i get collapseOne id but I want test1 id